# MySQL, carregar ao contrario

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, caso eu adicione algum arquivo aqui ele vai para o final da lista, porem eu quero que ele vá para o começo.

[image]

Código que executa isso

```
if($sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM arquivos_downloads WHERE nome LIKE '%$palavra_chave%'"))
    {   
        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            if($i == $linha['id'] || $i != $linha['id'])
            {   
                $arq = $linha['nome'];

                $arq_title = $arq;

                $arq_nome = substr($linha['nome'], 0, 50);
                $arq_nome = str_replace("_", " ", $arq_nome);

                for($icont = 0; $icont <= 10000; $icont++)
                {
                    $arq_nome = str_replace("[".$icont."]", "", $arq_nome);
                    $arq_title = str_replace("[".$icont."]", "", $arq_title);
                }

                $torrent = new Torrent("Uploads/".$arq.".torrent");

        ?>      
                <div id="lista_arquivos_painel">
                    <div id="lista_arquivos_informacoes">
                        <div id="nome_arquivo_div">
                            <span id="nome_arquivo" title="<? echo $arq_title ?>"><b><? echo $arq_nome; ?></b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tamanho_arquivo_div">
                            <span id="tamanho_arquivo" class="informacoes"><b><? echo $torrent->size(2); ?></b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="arquivos_arquivo_div">
                            <span id="arquivos_arquivo" class="informacoes"><b>3</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tempo_arquivo_div">
                            <span id="tempo_arquivo" class="informacoes"><b>9 dias</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="seeds_arquivo_div">
                            <span id="seeds_arquivo" class="informacoes"><b>15234</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="leechs_arquivo_div">
                            <span id="leechs_arquivo" class="informacoes"><b>16785</b></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="lista_arquivos_botoes" href="#" id="botao_magnet">
                        <div id="botao_magnet_div">
                            <a href="<? echo $torrent->magnet(); ?>" target="_top" id="botao_magnet"><b>MAGNET</b></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="botao_torrent_div">    
                            <a id="botao_torrent" href="<? echo "baixar.php?arquivo=Uploads/".$arq.".torrent" ?>"><b>.TORRENT</b></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?       
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Já testaste com `ORDER BY nome DESC`?

Comment: Já consegui resolver, Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes dizer ao MySQL como queres ordenar os resultados. Se usares

```
ORDER BY nome DESC
```

isso quer dizer: ordenar pelo campo `nome` com ordem descendente.

A query completa seria

```
"SELECT * FROM arquivos_downloads WHERE nome LIKE '%$palavra_chave%' ORDER BY nome DESC"
```

Comment: Olá, não quero organizar por ordem alfabética e sim por posição, os mais recentes primeiro.

Comment: @LucasCarezia tens algum campo na BD com essa informação? ID? podes ordenar por esse campo.

Comment: Funcionou sim, obrigado